# Automate Setting IDs according to Number of Instances

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, c++17

I have a simple method in my class, which sets Ids

```
void Instructor::setInstrID(const int newInstrID)
{
     instrID = newInstrID;
}
```

I want that instead of manually setting the id, I formulate a way such that the first instance of Instructor gets the id 0 automatically and when the second one is initialized, it should automatically have the `Id = 1` and so on. Now I am not sure how to do this.

Should this be within the method? Or should it be in my `main()` function? How could I check if there are any existing instances? I thought of making a vector but then that would be in `main()` and I didn't really wanna do that. Any leads?

Comment: Bear in mind what kind of restrictions such a design puts on your clients—if ever you end up with two different clients that want their own stream of IDs, you’ve denied them the utility of having a contiguous set numbered from 0 (as well as repeatability with unit tests and what not).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to add a `static` member that counts up the number of instances that have existed.

```
class foo
{
private:
    // Next ID to assign
    static unsigned int counter;

    // This instance's ID
    unsigned int instrID = counter++;
};

unsigned int foo::counter = 0;
```

You might run into problems if you create more instances than `unsigned int` can represent. It should be fine, as long as instances are destroyed in about the same order they are created.

If you want a thread safe alternative, you can use `std::atomic<unsigned int>` instead.